# UnicodeDecodeError with Python 2.7 and suds 4.0 with German language

Tags: python-2.7, unicode, utf-8, ascii, suds

I have a python-django project and I am trying to save German and Italian in my Postgresql database which is used only by this project. I am trying to send the results I want to save in database through an Html Form that I have added:

```
accept-charset="UTF-8"
```

The results are send to my views.py in which I have added on the top

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

I have also tried to encode,decode inside views.py into utf-8, ISO-5589-1, latin-1 but it is not working. I believe the error has to do with this article but I don't understand the solution they say the bug is fixed but still not working for me.

https://fedorahosted.org/suds/ticket/361

This is my traceback:

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST


Django Version: 1.4
Python Version: 2.7.2
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'ui')
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/hatzimin/web/indivo_ui_server/apps/problems/views.py" in new_problem
  281.                                                content_type='application/xml')
File "/home/hatzimin/web/indivo_ui_server/indivo_client_py/client.py" in __call__
  154.         return func(self.url, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/hatzimin/web/indivo_ui_server/indivo_client_py/client.py" in post
  68.         return self.request(self.api_base+uri, uri_params, method="POST", body=body, headers=headers)
File "/home/hatzimin/web/indivo_ui_server/indivo_client_py/client.py" in request
  132.         return super(IndivoClient, self).request(uri, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/hatzimin/web/indivo_ui_server/indivo_client_py/oauth2/__init__.py" in request
  697.             connection_type=connection_type)
File "/home/hatzimin/web/indivo_ui_server/indivo_client_py/oauth2/httplib2/__init__.py" in request
  1544.                     (response, content) = self._request(conn, authority, uri, request_uri, method, body, headers, redirections, cachekey)
File "/home/hatzimin/web/indivo_ui_server/indivo_client_py/oauth2/httplib2/__init__.py" in _request
  1294.         (response, content) = self._conn_request(conn, request_uri, method, body, headers)
File "/home/hatzimin/web/indivo_ui_server/indivo_client_py/oauth2/httplib2/__init__.py" in _conn_request
  1231.                 conn.request(method, request_uri, body, headers)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py" in request
  955.         self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py" in _send_request
  989.         self.endheaders(body)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py" in endheaders
  951.         self._send_output(message_body)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py" in _send_output
  809.             msg += message_body

Exception Type: UnicodeDecodeError at /apps/problems/problems/new
Exception Value: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 207: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: I found a solution but I cannot post it as an answer, I am redirected to a blankpage. So I added this in my views.py : problem_xml= problem_xml.encode('ascii', 'xmlcharrefreplace')  and then the procedure completed correctly. The German characters saved with umlaut in database. Tested also with Greek and Itallian

Answer (score 0):

Probably `suds` is returning string of type `'str'` encoded in `utf-8`. You should convert this string to type `'unicode'` before working with it.

Try invoking `django.utils.encoding.smart_unicode` on it right after you receive the string from `suds`.

Comment: Do you know how can I find where to add this?

Comment: @user1431148 this function should be invoked right after you receive the result from suds